# checkbox with calculated field in report

Tags: ms-access, report, calculated-field, iif

I'm working on a report and am creating some calculated text fields.  I have a checkbox, and if it is checked, I want it to calculate a value, and if unchecked return 0.

Basically I'm trying to get:
if checkbox = true, then count[field]*15
if checkbox = false, then 0

I'm very new and am still trying to grasp IIF statements, and am having trouble getting the right syntax. Thanks for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this expression:

```
=Count([Field])*15*Abs([YourCheckbox])
```